# Shouldn't the default path when creating and accessing files in Java be with the jar?

Tags: java, linux, path, ide

I'm having a problem when I create or access files from my IDE (Netbeans) the new files popup in the project's folder **but** when I run the jar from the Linux terminal, Linux mint terminal command, the file access is in my /home/user folder.

The following code shows a path to my "/home/user" folder.

```
showMessageDialog(null, new File("").getAbsolutePath());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you run your Java program from `/home/user`? You probably did, didn't you?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory

Comment: No. I ran it from the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to get the path to the jar. Maybe this will help someone else.

Here is a method that returns the path of the jar's folder.

```
/**
 * Gets the path to the folder of the jar file
 * @return Returns the path to the jar's folder
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
 */
static String getJarPath() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    // Get path to the jar
    String path = Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
    // Decode the path whitespaces
    String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");

    // Remove the jar from the end of the path //

    // Path variable that will be returned
    String newPath = File.separator;

    // Path split by file separator
    String[] pathSplit = decodedPath.split(File.separator);

    // Add each of the strings to the new path except the last one
    for (int i = 0; i < pathSplit.length-1; i++) {

        // Add a link of the path
        newPath += pathSplit[i] + File.separator;
    }

    // Return the path to the folder with the jar
    return newPath;
}
```